# Javax validation inside of list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

So I have a class and a field that is list of strings and I want to validate every one of them, but it's not working, I tried this and this didn't work out:

```
public class Info {
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private List<@Email(message = "uncorrect email") String> emails;
}
```

I also tried this and it didn't work:

```
public class Info {
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private @Valid List<@Email(message = "uncorrect email") String> emails;
}
```

But when it's just one String it works fine.

```
public class Info {
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private @Email(message = "uncorrect email") String email;
}
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Do the `@NotNull` and `@NotEmpty` validations work? Wherever this class is being referenced, have you marked it as `@Valid` and the corresponding class or method as `@Validated`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest versions of hibernate validator support it. You can go with the following changes to achieve the desired validation behaviour.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Java Bean

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class Info {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private List<@Email(message = "List contain atleast one incorrect email") String> emails;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email(message = "incorrect email")
    private String email;

    public List<String> getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }

    public void setEmails(List<String> emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Info [emails=" + emails + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

Adding the `@Valid`

```
@PostMapping("/post")
public void post(@RequestBody @Valid Info info) {
    System.out.println(info);
}
```